# XSL: descendants only with certain ancestor

Tags: xslt

What is an XSL expression that will select all B's that only have A's as ancestors? eg these (where I can already locate R via an expression):

```
  R/A/B
  R/A/A/B
  R/A/A.../A/B
```

but not this

```
  R/A/X/A/B
```

Comment: Is `R` the root element, or can `R` itself have other ancestor nodes?

Comment: You haven't stated which XSLT/XPath version you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.0 and above you can do

```
.//B except .//*[not(self::A)]//B
```

But since you ask for an XSLT solution rather than a pure XPath solution then a selective recursive descent to reach the relevant B elements might work better:

```
<xsl:template match="A" mode="aab">
  <!-- When we find an A, go on to its children -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="aab">
  <!-- When we find something that isn't an A, go no further -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B" mode="aab">
  <!-- This is one of the B elements we are interested in -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following matching expression:

```
//B[count(ancestor::A) = count(ancestor::*[not(self::R)])]
```

An XSL template using this expression could be

```
<xsl:template match="B[count(ancestor::A) = count(ancestor::*[not(self::R)])]">
  CONDITION FULFILLED!
</xsl:template>
```